# mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function bcpow()

Tags: php, syntax-error

I'm trying to get my CMS script installed on my server everything works perfectly on Xampp however when I install it on my server (VPS) it installs perfectly fine and I can access the script(website pages) but not the admin panel (it is giving me a blank page after entering the password)

Apache Error log says:

```
[Wed May 06 20:14:22.677240 2020] [fcgid:warn] [pid 18988] [client 12x.x8.xxx.xxx:49816] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function bcpow() in /home/example/public_html/application/system/function_security.php on line 75, referer: https://www.example.com/admin/
```

This is my function_security.php

```
<?php
require_once ("launcher.php");
//--
    function PHP_DatesCrypt($action, $string) {
        global $options_launcher;
        $output             = false;
        $encrypt_method     = "AES-256-CBC";
        $secret_key         = $options_launcher['crypt_secret_key'];
        $secret_iv          = $options_launcher['crypt_password'];
        // hash
        $key                = hash('sha256', $secret_key);

        // iv - encrypt method AES-256-CBC expects 16 bytes - else you will get a warning
        $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);
        if ( $action == 'encrypt' ) {
            $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
            $output = base64_encode($output);
        } else if( $action == 'decrypt' ) {
            $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
        }
        return $output;
    }
//--
    function PHP_Crypt_code($in, $to_num = false, $pad_up = false, $pass_key = null) {
        $out   =   '';
        $index = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
        $index.= 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $index.= '0123456789';
        $base  = strlen($index);

        if ($pass_key !== null) {

            for ($n = 0; $n < strlen($index); $n++) {
                $i[] = substr($index, $n, 1);
            }

            $pass_hash = hash('sha256',$pass_key);
            $pass_hash = (strlen($pass_hash) < strlen($index) ? hash('sha512', $pass_key) : $pass_hash);

            for ($n = 0; $n < strlen($index); $n++) {
                $p[] =  substr($pass_hash, $n, 1);
            }

            array_multisort($p, SORT_DESC, $i);
            $index = implode($i);
        }

        if ($to_num) {
            // Digital number  <<--  alphabet letter code
            $len = strlen($in) - 1;

            for ($t = $len; $t >= 0; $t--) {
                @$bcp = bcpow($base, $len - $t);
                @$out = $out + strpos($index, substr($in, $t, 1)) * $bcp;
            }

            if (is_numeric($pad_up)) {
                $pad_up--;

                if ($pad_up > 0) {
                    $out -= pow($base, $pad_up);
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Digital number  -->>  alphabet letter code
            if (is_numeric($pad_up)) {
                $pad_up--;

                if ($pad_up > 0) {
                    $in += pow($base, $pad_up);
                }
            }

            for ($t = ($in != 0 ? floor(log($in, $base)) : 0); $t >= 0; $t--) {
                $bcp = bcpow($base, $t);
                @$a   = floor($in / $bcp) % $base;
                $out = $out . substr($index, $a, 1);
                @$in  = $in - ($a * $bcp);
            }
        }

        return $out;
    }
//--
/* function PHP_UserData($data_request = array('value' => '', 'direct_query' => 0, 'loggedin' => true)){}  */
//--
    function PHP_Message_EMAIL($data = array()) {
        global $load, $con, $mail, $options_launcher;

        $smtp_or_mail       = $options_launcher['smtp_or_mail'];
        $smtp_host          = $options_launcher['smtp_host'];
        $smtp_username      = $options_launcher['smtp_username'];
        $smtp_password      = $options_launcher['smtp_password'];
        $smtp_encryption    = $options_launcher['smtp_encryption'];
        $smtp_port          = $options_launcher['smtp_port'];


        $email_from      = $smtp_username;
        $to_email        = $data['to_email'] = PHP_Secure($data['to_email']);
        $subject         = $data['subject'];
        $data['charSet'] = PHP_Secure($data['charSet']);
        if (@$smtp_or_mail == 'mail') {
            $mail->IsMail();
        } else if (@$smtp_or_mail == 'smtp') {
            $mail->isSMTP();
            $mail->Host        = $smtp_host;
            $mail->SMTPAuth    = true;
            $mail->Username    = $smtp_username;
            $mail->Password    = $smtp_password;
            $mail->SMTPSecure  = $smtp_encryption;
            $mail->Port        = $smtp_port;
            $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
                'ssl' => array(
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                    'allow_self_signed' => true
                )
            );
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        $mail->IsHTML($data['is_html']);
        $mail->setFrom($smtp_username, $data['from_name']);
        $mail->addAddress($data['to_email'], $data['to_name']);
        $mail->Subject = $data['subject'];
        $mail->CharSet = $data['charSet'];
        $mail->MsgHTML($data['message_body']);
        if ($mail->send()) {
            $mail->ClearAddresses();
            return true;
        }
    }
//--    
/*  function PHP_UsernameExists($username = '') {
        global $db;
        return ($db->where('username', PHP_Secure($username))->getValue(T_USER, 'count(*)') > 0) ? true : false;
    } */
//--    
/*  function PHP_UserEmailExists($username = '') {
        global $db;
        return ($db->where('email', PHP_Secure($username))->getValue(T_USER, 'count(*)') > 0) ? true : false;
    } */
//--
    function PHP_Install_rmdir() {  
        $files = glob('install/*'); //obtenemos todos los nombres de los ficheros
        foreach($files as $file){
            if(is_file($file))
            unlink($file); //elimino el fichero
        }
        @rmdir('install');
    }
//--
    function PHP_fetchToken($form){
        $token  =   md5(uniqid(microtime(), true));
        $_SESSION['token'][$form]   =   $token; 
        // Just return it, don't echo and return
        return $token;
    }
//--
    function PHP_matchToken($form){
        if(!isset($_POST['token'][$form]))
            return false;
        // I would clear the token after matched
        if($_POST['token'][$form] === $_SESSION['token'][$form]) {
            $_SESSION['token'][$form]   =   NULL;
            return true;
        }
        // I would return false by default, not true
        return false;
    }   
//--    
?>
```

I don't understand why it is ok on Xampp but not on my server. I have even installed the same PHP version which is in Xampp

I'm not expert in this so I kindly ask someone to help

Thank you

Edit:
Now no more blank page after installing **bcmath** but the page redirect back to homepage still no admin page/panel loads.

Apache new error:

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/example/public_html/application/system/DB/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/example/public_html/application/system/DB/vendor/autoload.php on line 5
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/example/public_html/application/system/DB/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/example/public_html/application/system/DB/vendor/autoload.php on line 5
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  require(/home/example/public_html/application/system/DB/vendor/composer/../joshcam/mysqli-database-class/MysqliDb.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/example/public_html/application/system/DB/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/example/public_html/application/system/DB/vendor/composer/../joshcam/mysqli-database-class/MysqliDb.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/example/public_html/application/system/DB/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  require(/home/example/public_html/application/system/DB/vendor/composer/../joshcam/mysqli-database-class/MysqliDb.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/example/public_html/application/system/DB/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/example/public_html/application/system/DB/vendor/composer/../joshcam/mysqli-database-class/MysqliDb.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/example/public_html/application/system/DB/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
```

This is the autoload_real.php

```
<?php

// autoload_real.php @generated by Composer

class ComposerAutoloaderInit60bcbf6306fdeb83c78ecf96a45a2c2f
{
    private static $loader;

    public static function loadClassLoader($class)
    {
        if ('Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader' === $class) {
            require __DIR__ . '/ClassLoader.php';
        }
    }

    public static function getLoader()
    {
        if (null !== self::$loader) {
            return self::$loader;
        }

        spl_autoload_register(array('ComposerAutoloaderInit60bcbf6306fdeb83c78ecf96a45a2c2f', 'loadClassLoader'), true, true);
        self::$loader = $loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();
        spl_autoload_unregister(array('ComposerAutoloaderInit60bcbf6306fdeb83c78ecf96a45a2c2f', 'loadClassLoader'));

        $useStaticLoader = PHP_VERSION_ID >= 50600 && !defined('HHVM_VERSION') && (!function_exists('zend_loader_file_encoded') || !zend_loader_file_encoded());
        if ($useStaticLoader) {
            require_once __DIR__ . '/autoload_static.php';

            call_user_func(\Composer\Autoload\ComposerStaticInit60bcbf6306fdeb83c78ecf96a45a2c2f::getInitializer($loader));
        } else {
            $map = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_namespaces.php';
            foreach ($map as $namespace => $path) {
                $loader->set($namespace, $path);
            }

            $map = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_psr4.php';
            foreach ($map as $namespace => $path) {
                $loader->setPsr4($namespace, $path);
            }

            $classMap = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php';
            if ($classMap) {
                $loader->addClassMap($classMap);
            }
        }

        $loader->register(true);

        if ($useStaticLoader) {
            $includeFiles = Composer\Autoload\ComposerStaticInit60bcbf6306fdeb83c78ecf96a45a2c2f::$files;
        } else {
            $includeFiles = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_files.php';
        }
        foreach ($includeFiles as $fileIdentifier => $file) {
            composerRequire60bcbf6306fdeb83c78ecf96a45a2c2f($fileIdentifier, $file);
        }

        return $loader;
    }
}

function composerRequire60bcbf6306fdeb83c78ecf96a45a2c2f($fileIdentifier, $file)
{
    if (empty($GLOBALS['__composer_autoload_files'][$fileIdentifier])) {
        require $file;

        $GLOBALS['__composer_autoload_files'][$fileIdentifier] = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure `bcmath` is installed on the server. Also, from the documentation, `These functions are only available if PHP was configured with --enable-bcmath`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes I was searching everywhere and I found this answer to install "bcmath" and I did install it not a few other errors in the log. I have edited my post above.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, it was PHP Execution Mode. currently, my root domain uses mod_php and it is not compatible with my 2nd CMS for some reason. When I change execution mode to FastCGI things start to work normally. I really don't know what is going on there but I'm glad that things are working the way I want now and I can live with that :)

Thank you again for your support